# How to change Scenes in JavaFX without FXML

Tags: css, javafx, scene

I'm trying to change Scenes in my Java FX program with resetting the Scene like

```
stage.setScene(new Scene(new StartupPane(stage),Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(),Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()));
```

Is this a proper way to do it?

I also have the problem that the CSS style doesn't apply on the new Scene after the change of a Scene. Is there a proper solution for it or do you recommend me to use FXML (actually I have no experience with FXML)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you want to change the scene? In general you can just change the root node of the scene and there is no need to change the scene itself.
2. Changing the scene can be done but this is independent of the question whether to use FXML or not.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, it's working fine now for me. I only found answers with changing the XML controller or something like that, therefore I asked  for XML.
Thanks